# When accessing a state variable from a useCallback, value is not updated

Tags: reactjs, callback, state, react-functional-component

At a certain place of my code I'm accessing a state variable of my component from a call back ( `UserCallback` ) and I find the state variable has not updated from the initial value and call back is referring to the initial value. As I read in the documentation when variable is passed as one of array items then it should update the function when it is updated. Following is a sample code.

```
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const node = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    increment() {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }
  }));

  const clickListener = useCallback(
    e => {
      if (!node.current.contains(e.target)) {
        alert(count);
      }
    },
    [count]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // Attach the listeners on component mount.
    document.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
    // Detach the listeners on component unmount.
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      ref={node}
      style={{ width: "500px", height: "100px", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
    >
      <h1>Hi {count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
});

const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button onClick={() => childRef.current.increment()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I'm originally building is a custom confirmation modal. I have a state variable which set either **display:block** or **display:none** to the root element. Then if there is a click outside the component I need to close the modal by setting state variable to **false**. Following is the original function.

```
  const clickListener = useCallback(
    (e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log('isVisible - ', isVisible, ' count - ', count, ' !node.current.contains(e.target) - ', !node.current.contains(e.target))
      if (isVisible && !node.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setIsVisible(false)
      }
    },
    [node.current, isVisible],
  )
```

It doesn't get closed because **isVisible** is always **false** which is the initial value.

What am I doing wrong here?

For further clarifications following is the full component.

```
const ConfirmActionModal = (props, ref) => {

  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsVisible(true)
    setCount(1)
  }

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      showModal: showModal
    }
  });

  const node = useRef(null)
  const stateRef = useRef(isVisible);

  const escapeListener = useCallback((e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
      setIsVisible(false)
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = isVisible;
  }, [isVisible]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const clickListener = e => {
      if (stateRef.current && !node.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setIsVisible(false)
      }
    };

    // Attach the listeners on component mount.
    document.addEventListener('click', clickListener)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', escapeListener)
    // Detach the listeners on component unmount.
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', clickListener)
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', escapeListener)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={node}>
      <ConfirmPanel style={{ display : isVisible ? 'block': 'none'}}>
        <ConfirmMessage>
          Complete - {isVisible.toString()} - {count}
        </ConfirmMessage>
        <PrimaryButton
          type="submit"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#00aa10",
            color: "white",
            marginRight: "10px",
            margin: "auto"
          }}
          onClick={() => {console.log(isVisible); setCount(2)}}
        >Confirm</PrimaryButton>
      </ConfirmPanel>
    </div>

  )

}

export default forwardRef(ConfirmActionModal)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign a function `clickListener` to `document.addEventListener` **on component mount**, this function [has a closure](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjjuZiwydHqAhUJT8AKHZIBA5oQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FClosures&usg=AOvVaw2FJH0AxYHDDvLjiTXjDjq9) on `count` value.

On the next render, the `count` value will be stale.

One way to solve it is implementing a function with refernce closure instead:

```
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const countRef = useRef(count);

  useEffect(() => {
    countRef.current = count;
  }, [count]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // countRef.current always holds the most updated state
    const clickListener = e => {
      if (!node.current.contains(e.target)) {
        alert(countRef.current);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
    };
  }, []);
...
}
```

[image: Edit fast-wood-stsrn]

Comment: What you said is true but I think OP's question is about why `isVisible` is always false. I think OP has created a confusion by posting two versions of `clickListener` function

Comment: The OP didn't show where `isVisible` comes from and how he handles it

Comment: yes and that is something OP should clarify because question is about `isVisible` always being false

Comment: Full component is posted with the question

Comment: BTW the solution works. Still need to get my head around this and understand what exactly was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callback to setIsvisible so you don't need `isVisible` as a dependency of the `useCallback`. Adding `node.current` is pointless since node is a ref and gets mutated:

```
const clickListener = useCallback((e) => {
  setIsVisible((isVisible) => {//pass callback to state setter
    if (isVisible && !node.current.contains(e.target)) {
      return false;
    }
    return isVisible;
  });
}, []);//no dependencies needed
```

Answer (score 1):

While your `clickListener` does change when `count` changes you only bind the initial `clickListener` once on mount because your `useEffect` dependency list is empty. You could ad `clickListener` to the dependency list as well:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Attach the listeners on component mount.
    document.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
    // Detach the listeners on component unmount.
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
    };
}, [clickListener]);
```

Side note: using `node.current` in a dependency list doesn't do anything as react does not notice any changes to a ref. Dependencies can only be state or props.

Comment: You will assign and remove an event listener on every render... That's not recommended, you also can just add `onClick` to the outer div...

Comment: Yes, but in his case, you can only render by changing `count`...

Comment: "those kind of changes all over every react app"? Querying the DOM in React is basically what you don't want to do since you using React.

Comment: I'm not optimizing, I'm saying it's not recommended to do it in a way you did. Take it or leave it, good luck.

Comment: "super cheap", "totally fine" are your opinions, React has its event system using [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), if in your opinion acessing DOM events are better design choice as you recommend so be it. Please don't tag me, I don't see any point in it.

Comment: @DennisVash To clean up that clutter: It's not updating on **every state change** and also not on every render like you initially claimed, only when `count` changes. It is not *querying the DOM* in that it searches for any DOM elements, it is simply removing and adding a listener. It better readable and maintainable than your solution. Also it is better suited to illustrate why OPs code was not working as expected. The recommendation to not query the DOM, which I am totally aware of, means to not query DOM elements and/or mutate them if they are managed by react. This doesn't apply here.